# Testing a method that accepts callback function that doesn't return a value in Golang

Tags: unit-testing, go, spy

I'm trying to test the following function:

```
// SendRequestAsync sends request asynchronously, accepts callback
//  func, which it invokes
//
// Parameters:
// - `context` : some context
// - `token` : some token
// - `apiURL` : the URL to hit
// - `callType` : the type of request to make. This should be one of
//  the HTTP verbs (`"GET"`, `"POST"`, `"PUT"`, `"DELETE"`, ...)
// - `callBack` : the func to invoke upon completion
// - `callBackCustomData`: the data to invoke `callBack` with
//
// Since this is an async request, it doesn't return anything.
func (a *APICoreSt) SendRequestAsync(context interface{}, token string, apiURL string, callType APIType, header map[string]string, jsonBody []byte,
    callBack OnCompletion, callBackCustomData interface{}) {
    go func(data interface{}) {
        callBack(a.SendRequest(context, token, apiURL, callType, header, jsonBody), data)
    }(callBackCustomData)
}
```

where `OnCompletion` is defined by:

```
type OnCompletion func(result CallResultSt, data interface{})
```

My mind instantly thinks to create a spy callback. To do so, I forked [this framework](https://godoc.org/github.com/nyarly/spies), came up with the following:

```
// outside the test function
type MySpy struct {
    *spies.Spy
}

func (my *MySpy) Callback(res CallResultSt, data interface{}) {
    my.Called(res, data)
    fmt.Println("Hello world")
    return
}

//in the test function
spy := new(MySpy)

//...some table-driven test logic the generator came up with, containing my data

spy.MatchMethod("Callback", spies.AnyArgs)
assert.NotEmpty(t, spies.CallsTo("Callback"))
```

and it greeted me with

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recovered]
    panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

How do I remedy this, and test this method?

Comment: Could you please try to reduce this to a simpler, complete problem? In particular, tell us how the callback type `OnCompletion` is defined, and show a complete test function.

Comment: As for "reducing this to a simpler problem", this is as simple as it can get. The only thing I'm leaving out of the test function is the table-driven stuff the test generator came up with.

Comment: @MikeWarren Which of the lines you showed caused the panic?

Comment: The `spy.MatchMethod` line is where the panic occurred. I remove it and the assert below it, and the test passes.

Comment: @MikeWarren then show where and how you initialize `spy`, and what type it is.

Comment: `spy := new(MySpy)` before the test, in the test function

Comment: What is `spy`, and when you forked that project, what changes did you make in your fork?

Comment: @MikeWarren but if it is exactly on that line, not some line inside that method, then that means that `spy` is nil, most probably.

Comment: @MikeWarren `new(MySpy)` will not automagically initialize the embedded field. `*spies.Spy` is `nil`.

Comment: `assert.NotNil(t, spy)` passed.

Comment: The simplest option, if it is one, is to delete the method. It serves no purpose other than removing type safety. It's not hard for the caller to just call `SendRequest` in a goroutine if it desires asynchronous behaviour: https://play.golang.org/p/_s9-8l6sGco

Comment: I fixed the pointer issue (thanks @mkopriva). Also, now my test fails, and I have no idea how to handle the async stuff so that it passes. Unfortunately, I am not in charge of the code base under test itself, only the testing of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would ditch the spy stuff. This task is simple enough that you shouldn't need an external dependency to handle it. You could instead make your own "spy" that has a channel it passes args into when the function is called. In your test, you then attempt to receive from the channel. That will force the test to wait for the callback function to be called. You may also consider adding a timeout period so that the test can fail instead of blocking forever if the function is never called.

```
// outside the test function
type MySpy struct {
    Args chan MySpyArgs
}

type MySpyArgs struct {
    Res  CallResultSt
    Data interface{}            
}

func (my *MySpy) Callback(res CallResultSt, data interface{}) {
    my.Args <- MySpyArgs{Res: res, Data: data}
}

//in the test function
spyChan := make(chan MySpyArgs)
spy := &MySpy{spyChan}

//...some table-driven test logic the generator came up with, containing my data

args := <-spyChan
// can now assert arguments were as you expected, etc.
```

A crude working example: https://play.golang.org/p/zUYpjXdkz-4.

And if you want to use a timeout:

```
...
select {
case args := <-spyChan:
    // assertions on args
case <-time.After(5 * time.Second):
    // prevent blocking for over 5 seconds and probably fail the test
}
```

Comment: Regarding the "adding a timeout period", is that done simply with `time.After`?